# Is $f$ surjective and injective?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f$ be a function from $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(a) = (-1)^aa$. Decide whether $f$ is injective and whether it is surjective.

Which function do I start with in determining this? Thanks

Comment: How would you get $-2$?

Comment: You start with the function $f$. To show injectivity, you need to show $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$ and to show surjectivity, you need to show $\forall~y\in\Bbb Z~,~\exists~x\in\Bbb N~$ such that $f(x)=y$

Comment: Do note that $f$ is not surjective since there is no pre-image for the elements of the set $(-2\Bbb Z^+)\cup (-1+2\Bbb Z^+)\subseteq\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to show formally that $f$ is not surjective, by showing that there is no $a$ such as $f(a)=3$.

We will use the fact that $\forall a,|f(a)|=a$.

So $f(n)=3 \Rightarrow |f(n)|=3 \Rightarrow n=3$, but $f(3)=-3$, so $f$ is not surjective.

For the injectivity, if $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow |f(a)|=|f(b)| \Rightarrow a=b$, so $f$ is injective